# Django PK to slugfield

Tags: python, django, slug

I want to change my urls from PK to slugfields, but on one field this is not working.

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    url(r'^indexed/$', views.QuestionsIndexListView.as_view(), name='index_all'),
    url(r'^ask-question/$', views.CreateQuestionView.as_view(), name='ask_question'),
    url(r'^(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$', views.QuestionDetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),
    url(r'^propose-answer/(?P<question_id>\d+)/$', views.CreateAnswerView.as_view(), name='propose_answer'), 
    #url(r'^propose-answer/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$', views.CreateAnswerView.as_view(), name='propose_answer'),
]
```

views

```
class CreateAnswerView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Answer
    fields = ["content", ]
    message = _("Thank you!")

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.user = self.request.user
        form.instance.question_id = self.kwargs["question_id"]
        return super().form_valid(form)

    def get_success_url(self):
        messages.success(self.request, self.message)
        return reverse(
            "question_detail", kwargs={"pk": self.kwargs["question_id"]})
```

My first problem is, on my way it is not possible to open with a slug url. I get this error.

> Reverse for 'propose_answer' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1
>   pattern(s) tried: ['propose-answer/(?P[-\w]+)/$']

And my second problem, when the form is valid, how can I forward to the slug url again? This is not the same Model. I have two models. Question and Answer. And after publishing the answer, I want go back to the Main Question like the url

```
url(r'^(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$', views.QuestionDetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),
```

--
update

In the posted urls.py, I have two lines for propose-answer, one line is outcommend. I wish to use propose-answer with slug as I tried in the outcommend line, but when I try this I get the displaed error.

Comment: It doesn't appear that the code you have posted corresponds to the error message you are getting. The error suggests you are trying to reverse a URL with the name `propose_answer` and a single argument which is an empty string. Could you clarify that in your post?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
re_path(r'^(?P<slug>[\w\-]+)/$',  views.QuestionDetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),
```

Then for the success you could use

```
def get_success_url(self):
    return self.request.path
```